# Error while updating content to Google sites through API

Tags: java, google-sites

The code to insert document data works for Google sites but for update it fails.

I tried below two calls

1

```
entry.setMediaSource(ms);
```

gives following

> //IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set media source on entry with existing non-MediaContent

2

```
service.updateMedia(new URL(getContentFeedUrl()), newAttachment);
```

gives

> //com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException,Invalid request URI

service is sites service object, entry is attachment entry

Let me know if you need more info,

Answer (score 0):

finally it seemed to work through media content object, i have kept the complete code snippet at http://dsteps.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-update-content-through-google.html